# Forecasting differentiated timeseries with ARMA?

Tags: arma, garch, stationarity

If I apply ARMA on a stationary differentiated time series and want to make forecasts with this model, the forecast will be on the differentiated values. I need the values to be non-differentiated, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forecast $\Delta X_t$ then to get the forecast of $X_t$ simply sum up the differences:

\begin{align*}
\hat{X}_{t+1}&=\hat{\Delta X_{t+1}}+X_t\\
\hat{X}_{t+2}&=\hat{\Delta X_{t+2}}+\hat{\Delta X_{t+1}}+X_t\\
... &\\
\hat{X}_{t+h}& =\hat{\Delta X_{t+h}}+\Delta \hat{X}_{t+h-1}+...+\hat{\Delta X_{t+1}}+X_t
\end{align*}

where we assume that $X_t$ is the last known in-sample value.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought! Is there a easy way of doing this in r? I'm using rugarch for the forecast!

Comment: Use function `cumsum`. If `dx` is your forecasted differences then the level forecast is `cumsum(dx)+xt`.